# Alluxio - access existing files in underfs

Tags: filesystems, hdfs, bigdata, alluxio

I am running a small Alluxio (1.7.0) cluster using Swift as the underfs.

I've confirmed Alluxio works great writing and reading files and persisting them to the Swift store.

I would like to access files on the Swift store via Alluxio that are saved from a separate client, but since there's no metadata in the Alluxio master these new files are not visible. I understand this is intended functionality, but I'm asking if there are any configuration options or workarounds to making new files in the underfs visible in Alluxio?

Answer (score 1):

You can make new UFS files known to Alluxio by forcing Alluxio to load the UFS metadata. This can be done with the `ls -f` command. the `-f` option forces the load from UFS, to discover UFS files. The [ls documentation](https://www.alluxio.org/docs/1.7/en/Command-Line-Interface.html#ls) has more details on the command. For example:

`bin/alluxio fs ls -f /mnt/swift/dir/`

will discover new UFS files in the `/mnt/swift/dir/` directory.

Comment: Awesome -- yes, it was in the friendly manual. Getting my head around the new command line.